# css overflow scroll issue

Tags: css

I have below div with

```
<div style="height:900px;width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden">
//content here

</div>
```

My problem is when i scroll right or left ,div border is not appearing.So it's look like 
cutting the data.I tried so many ways but no luck .Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: You have no border set on the div so it can't appear. Also what browser? Overflow-x,y is not supported always.

Answer (score 0):

Set padding to your div. Like this:

```
<div style="height:900px;width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;padding:5px;">
//content here

</div>
```

This will ensure the inside contents remain distant from the div.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, you aren't giving the `div` a border.
Try changing your code to this (adding border CSS property):

```
<div style="height:900px;width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;border:2px solid black">

    <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```

Also, like Naveed said, try adding padding (`padding:5px;` for example) to guarantee that your content remains within the div and doesn't flow over or get clipped.

Comment: i tried this and not working,Still border not appearing.If i scroll completely to right,then boder appearing

Comment: You probably already know this, but keep in mind that `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are CSS3 properties, and won't work in all browsers.

Comment: I have typed up a little demo that I think might help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/techappetite/rBzT7/